# XMPPFramework "typing.." status for message

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using robbiehanson/XMPPFramework for my current project.
How to get the message typing status using XMPPFramework? There  XEP- 184 protocol but those are deprecated right now .
Need assistance here for getting composing status in iOS .
Regards,
Bhat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most commonly used protocol for "contact is typing" notifications is [XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html).  As described in more detail there, the first message to a contact should contain an "active" state element (next to the `<body/>` element):

```
<active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
```

If the contact responds with a chat state, the client can go ahead and use other states, such as "composing":

```
<composing xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
```

or "paused" (the user has entered text, but isn't actively typing):

```
<paused xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
```

or "inactive", and finally "gone" when the user ends the conversation by closing the chat window or similar.

Comment: Will this work for the muc as our server crash when this stanza is sent for the muc jid but is totally working fine for single chat. Any inputs

Comment: Yes, this should work for MUC as well, as described in [section 5.5 of XEP-0085](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html#bizrules-groupchat). There's no reason this should crash the server. It might be worth filing a bug report with the server vendor.

Comment: Thanks Legoscia, Its working with the MUC Chat as well as confirmed.

Answer (score 8):

First you import:

```
#import "XMPPMessage+XEP_0085.h"
```

and then you add the following methods according to your purpose.

composing.....

```
- (void)sendComposingChatToUser:(XMPPJID*)jid {
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
    XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];
    [xmppMessage addComposingChatState];
    [xmppStream sendElement:message];
}
```

Active.....

```
- (void)sendActiveChatToUser:(XMPPJID*)jid {
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
    XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];
    [xmppMessage addActiveChatState];
    [xmppStream sendElement:message];
}
```

Inactive...

```
- (void)sendInactiveChatToUser:(XMPPJID*)jid {
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
    XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];
     [xmppMessage addInactiveChatState];
    [xmppStream sendElement:message];
}
```

Gone...

```
- (void)sendExitChatToUser:(XMPPJID*)jid {
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
    XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];
    [xmppMessage addGoneChatState];
   [xmppStream sendElement:xmppMessage];
}
```

Paused...

```
- (void)sendPausedChatToUser:(XMPPJID*)jid {
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
    XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];
    [xmppMessage addPausedChatState];
    [xmppStream sendElement:message];
}
```

then You should write following code in appdelgate. (didReceiveMessage) method.

Ex:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{
    if ([message isChatMessageWithBody]){
}
else{
if([message elementForName:@"composing"] != nil){



        } else if ([message elementForName:@"paused"] != nil) {



        } else if ([message elementForName:@"gone"] || [message elementForName:@"inactive"] ) {


        }
}
```

Comment: use the XMPP Clas import #import "XMPPMessage+XEP_0085.h"
and then use the function mentioned below. - (BOOL)hasChatState
- (BOOL)hasActiveChatState
- (BOOL)hasComposingChatState
- (BOOL)hasPausedChatState
- (BOOL)hasInactiveChatState
- (BOOL)hasGoneChatState
Example if([message hasGoneState]) .... more clean way.

Comment: Working like a charm for me. Thanks. :)