# smack api with typing to send the message

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am using the XMPP smack api 3.3.1 libraries. How do I send is typing information.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25041329/113848) might help.

Comment: Smack 3.3.1 is pretty old and contains security vulnerabilities. I recommend using Smack 4.

Comment: @flow I want to use smack 4, but could not connect to Facebook with smack4